# How to get Processing to take one item of an array in a text file and make a decision on it

Tags: java, arrays, integer, processing

I want to build a program that takes sound input and then creates an image out of different coloured circles out of this. I have a python backend, changing microphone input into integer values between -255 and 255, that is working fine. It saves all the data in real time to a txt file. My problem arises with how my Processing file deals with this information. I want it to take each item in the array as an integer and use it to make decisions, but I can't seem to make it happen.

The code below does nothing, and I get no error code. I've tried printing the array as below, and that works, but I want it to accept the actual content of the array and use it.

```
void draw() {
 String[] data = loadStrings("filename");
 for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
   int size = Math.abs(i);
   println(n);
   if(i < -182) {
     fill(0, 89, 132);
     ellipse(size, size, size, size);
   } else if(i < -109) {
```

etc

I expect it to create a circle of dimensions equal to that of the magnitude of the sound, and choose the colour based on the integer the python program has produced. The actual output is nothing.

Comment: You call println(n). What is n? I'm assuming println is a static import from System.out.

Comment: Also you're using the index `i` instead of the data in `data[i]` for your if statements. `i` will never trigger either of those conditions because `i` starts at 0 and you're checking that it's less than some negative number.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It prints out the contents of the txt file

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the index of your loop. In other words, it will take on values between 0 and data.length.

It looks to me like you want the actual `data` element stored in the `i`th position (`data[i]`). Keep in mind that this will be a string, so you will have to call a function to parse the value to an int, such as `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: How can I do this? `int content = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);` Would that work? And then use content in place of i in the if statements?

Comment: Correct. You probably want to replace other spots where you used `i` as well. For example, you probably want `size = Math.abs(content)`.